# How to delete/remove a bar3d in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

After i use the script below to create some axes3D and bar3D, i want to delete/remove a certain bars.

It seems i cannot use remove()/del functions/commands, since the bar3D doesn't support it?

If i use delaxes(), the whole axes would be deleted.

To make the bar3D transparent is also acceptable for me. But I cannot set the 'alpha' value of bar3D which are already created.

And it often shows "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" .

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.33))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,1, projection='3d')
ax1.set_xlim3d(0, 14)
ax1.set_ylim3d(0, 18)
ax1.set_zlim3d(0, 30)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,2,projection='3d')
ax2.set_xlim3d(0, 20)
ax2.set_ylim3d(0, 16)
ax2.set_zlim3d(0, 18)

ax3=fig.add_subplot(1,3,3,projection='3d')
ax3.set_xlim3d(0, 15)
ax3.set_ylim3d(0, 17)
ax3.set_zlim3d(0, 10)

ax1.bar3d(0,0,0,8,5,8, color='b', zsort='average')

ax2.bar3d(0,0,0,6,14,6, color='r', zsort='average')
ax2.bar3d(8,0,0,9,10,3, color='g', zsort='average')

ax3.bar3d(0,0,0,9,10,3, color='y', zsort='average')
ax3.bar3d(0,0,6,7,7,3, color='coral', zsort='average')

""" # I want to delete just the bar3d in ax3! None of them works.
bar3d.remove()
ax3.bar3d.remove()
del ax3.bar3d[0]
fig.delaxes(ax3)  
"""

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

`bar3d` creates `Poly3DCollection` objects. For each `Axes` object, they are stored in a list called `collections`:

```
In [31]: ax3.collections
Out[31]: 
[<mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection at 0x10bd67bd0>,
 <mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection at 0x109c822d0>]
```

So, to remove them, you can use any list operations, for example `pop()`:

```
ax3.collections.pop()
```

That will remove the last `Poly3DCollection` that you created